# Dplyr using conditional summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to see if I can see get total sums per group based on specific conditions/cases in the rows of the groups.

```
Group_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
Date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-02")
Time = c("12:01:10", "12:05:22", "12:07:30", "12:30:20", "12:37:20",  "11:10:01", "11:48:19", "11:50:18", "12:08:22", "12:08:57")
Color = c("blue", "red", "red", "green", NA, "blue", "blue", "green", "red", NA)
Status = c("go", "go", "go", "go", "end", "go", "go", "go", "go", "end")

df = data.frame(Group_ID, Date, Time, Color, Status)
df
```

output of table is:

```
# Group_ID       Date     Time Color Status
# 1         1 2022-01-01 12:01:10  blue     go
# 2         1 2022-01-01 12:05:22   red     go
# 3         1 2022-01-01 12:07:30   red     go
# 4         1 2022-01-01 12:30:20 green     go
# 5         1 2022-01-01 12:37:20  <NA>    end
# 6         2 2022-01-02 11:10:01  blue     go
# 7         2 2022-01-02 11:48:19  blue     go
# 8         2 2022-01-02 11:50:18 green     go
# 9         2 2022-01-02 12:08:22   red     go
# 10        2 2022-01-02 12:08:57  <NA>    end
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
df %>% 
  mutate(duration_sec = case_when(
    lead(Group_ID) == Group_ID ~ as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(lead(Time), format="%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct(Time, format="%H:%M:%S")))
  )
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
  summarise(
    blue_duration = case_when(
      Color == "blue" ~ sum(duration_sec, na.rm=T)
      )
    )
```

with an expected output of:

```
# Group_ID blue_duration
# <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1        1             252
# 2        2             2417
```

But with my code as written above, I get this:

```
# Group_ID blue_duration
# <dbl>         <dbl>
#   1        1          2170
# 2        1            NA
# 3        1            NA
# 4        1            NA
# 5        1            NA
# 6        2          3536
# 7        2          3536
# 8        2            NA
# 9        2            NA
# 10        2            NA
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think you need the `group_by` before doing the `lead` i.e. `df %>% group_by(Group_ID) %>% 
  mutate(duration_sec = case_when(
    lead(Group_ID) == Group_ID ~ as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(lead(Time), format="%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct(Time, format="%H:%M:%S")))
  )) %>% filter(Color == "blue") %>% summarise(blue_duration = sum(duration_sec, na.rm = TRUE))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `group_by` before doing the `lead`

```r
 df %>% 
   group_by(Group_ID) %>%  
   mutate(duration_sec = case_when(lead(Group_ID) == Group_ID ~ as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXct(lead(Time), format="%H:%M:%S"), as.POSIXct(Time, format="%H:%M:%S"))))) %>% 
   filter(Color == "blue") %>% 
   summarise(blue_duration = sum(duration_sec, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This answer is taken from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73450927/dplyr-using-conditional-summarise#comment129711606_73450927)